# Selenium for Android apps? Tools to perform automated scripts over Android apps to run over an api

Tags: android, api, selenium, cron, automated-tests

Looking into how to run a script to automatically login to an app like WhatsApp for example on a simulated Android device.

The script would use my login details to begin a session and perform set actions on my behalf, via an API.

Has anyone tried something like this before? http://selendroid.io/native.html Looks promising.

Comment: you can try appium

Answer (score 0):

Below are few popular open source mobile automation tools

- Appium
- Robotium
- Selendroid

Among those I personally feel Appium is best.

Please refer below links to get more details about these tools and differenes.
https://saucelabs.com/blog/selendroid-vs-appium-which-to-choose-for-your-mobile-app-testing

https://softwaretestingtips2.wordpress.com/2014/11/26/appium-vs-robotium-a-simple-comparison/